# Adding headers to internal requests in Laravel 4

Tags: rest, symfony, laravel, laravel-4

I have an API centric setup built with Laravel 4, consisting of a REST API, frontend and adminpanel. Both frontend and adminpanel are consuming the API using internal requests.

I make internal requests like this:

```
$request = Request::create($endpoint, $method, $parameters, $cookies, $files, $server, $content);
$this->response = Route::dispatch($request);
```

And everything works fine.

Now I want to secure the API using [an approach similar to AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1928)'s and when I create the request above I want to also set some custom headers (api key, signature, timestamp).

I have not found a way to add headers to a custom request. Is this possible when using internal requests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out setting headers is as simple as doing

```
$request->headers->set('MyHeaderName', 'header value');
```

before dispatching the request.

The catch (and the reason this did not work when I tried) is that in the API I have to use 
`Route::getCurrentRequest()` to get my custom request (as opposed to just asking the Request facade):

```
$request = Route::getCurrentRequest();
$all_headers = $request->header();
$specific_header = $request->header("SomeHeaderName");
```

Comment: `Request::instance()->headers->set('MyHeaderName', 'header value');` is also possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could set the headers using a [application event](http://laravel.com/docs/lifecycle#application-events) in your `filters.php`

```
App::after(function($request, $response)
{
   $response->headers->set('key','value');
});
```

If you find your using a lot of them, moving them into their own [service provider](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc#service-providers) may provide for a better structure.

Comment: Thanks, but that would not work I'm afraid. I need to be able to attach headers in the way I can attach $cookies and then Route::dispatch() the whole thing.